how to make a window in javafx refresh
I'm creating a ray Casting application and in it I need to draw a frame every 30 seconds and delete the old one. But my stage waits for the end of the cycle and only then is it drawn. How can I make the window render several times?
while (true){
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            rayCasting();
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }

I tried moving stage.show() to different places in a loop but it didn't help

You cannot put Thread.sleep() on the FXAT. Look into the animation classes.
